# foreach loop inserting all the checkboxes (checked and unchecked)

Tags: php, html, mysql, loops, foreach

I have a form that generates html checkboxes using php which is shown below

```
<p><form name="university" action="/university_handler" method="post">
  <fieldset>
    <table class="table">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th><span class="help-block">University Department</span></th>                            
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>  
        <tr> 
          <td><?php 
            $query = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT university_department FROM university WHERE university_id = '$university_id'") 
                or die  ("Could not search!");
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
              $university_department = $row['university_department'];
              $_SESSION['university_department'] = $university_department;
              $universityDepartment = $_SESSION['university_department'];
              echo "<label><input type='checkbox' name='university_department[]' value='{$universityDepartment}'>$universityDepartment</label><br><input type='text' value='' name='professor_name[{$universityDepartment}]' placeholder='Professor-Name'><input type='text' value='' name='class_name[{$universityDepartment}]' placeholder='Class-Name'>";}
          ?></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table> 
    <button type="submit" name="Submit"class="btn btn-info">Submit</button>
  </fieldset>
</form></p>
```

Now when I use my `university_handler` to insert the values into the database all of the check boxes are inserting instead of just the ones that have been checked off. I've been trying a range of things be nothing seems to be working. Here is the handler.

```
<?php
session_start();
include("connect.php");

$university_id = $_SESSION['university_id'];

// check if share_form is submitted and not empty
$error_message = "";
if(is_array($_POST['university_department']) && !empty($_POST['university_department'])){
  $error = array();
  $universityDepartment = $_POST['university_department'];
  if (count($universityDepartment)>0){
    foreach (str_replace('#', '', $_POST['class_name']) as $departmentName => $stripid){
      $class_name_backslash = $stripid . '/';
      $class_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $stripid);
      print_r($class_name);
    }
    $query_uni = ("INSERT INTO temp_list(departmentName, class_name, professor_name) VALUE ('$departmentName','$class_name', '$professor_name')");
    $q_u = mysqli_query($db, $query_uni) or die ('Error posting data');
}
}?>
```

Comment: why set three different variables only to use the last one? 
    `$university_department = $row['university_department'];`
    `$_SESSION['university_department'] = $university_department;`
    `$universityDepartment = $_SESSION['university_department'];`

Comment: just a little pro-tip: when you include files via `include` or `require`, you should use `include_once()` or `require_once()` so that later down the road when you are including files that include others, you do not get pinged for defining functions 2 times or causing longer load times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like @Martin's answer. The only thing i want to change is the `$_REQUEST`

When using `$_REQUEST` you are saying hey look at a post or get variable and use either value. So what happens if you have both a `$_POST` and a `$_GET` variable with the same name? One will be used while the other does not.

So lets use the same code in a different way.

```
$checkBoxName = (isset($_POST['checkBoxName']) ? $_POST['checkBoxName'] : (isset($_GET['checkBoxName']) ? $_GET['checkBoxName'] : ''));
if ($checkBoxName != '') {
    //do stuff here
}
```

This way since you can not see post info without using something like Google Chromes developer tools, its best to do it in this order so you check what is not seen before what you can see.

Hope this helps =)

EDIT:

Based on the information you gave me, i was able to come up with a way to insert only the classes you check off. Feel free to do the change this but this should work

```
<?php
$departList =   ($_POST['university_department'] ? $_POST['university_department'] : ($_GET['university_department'] ? $_GET['university_department'] : array()));
$classList =    ($_POST['class_name'] ? $_POST['class_name'] : ($_GET['class_name'] ? $_GET['class_name'] : array()));
$profList = ($_POST['professor_name'] ? $_POST['professor_name'] : ($_GET['professor_name'] ? $_GET['professor_name'] : array()));
if (count($departList) > 0) {
    foreach ($departList as $key => $val) {
        $class =    $classList[$val];
        $professor =    $profList[$val];
        $query_uni = ("INSERT INTO temp_list(departmentName, class_name, professor_name) VALUE ('$val','$class', '$professor')");
        $q_u = mysqli_query($db, $query_uni) or die ('Error posting data');
    }
}

?>
```

Good Luck =)

Comment: Hi! It works when I print out the $checkBoxName inside the if statment. What I did now is `if ($checkBoxName !=''){foreach(str_replace('#', '', $_POST['checkBoxName']) as $Name => $id){ 
     print_r($checkBoxName);
     print'<br>';}` Which prints all the check boxes.....

Comment: can you please give me a `print_r` or `var_dump` of your entire `$_POST` array. This will help me figure out what your looping through

Comment: After rereading your question i think i understand but let me just clarify. What you are asking is why is all the form information being inserted instead of only the ones where the checkbox is checked. Is this correct?

Comment: print_r of $_POST gives: Array ( [university_department] => Array ( [0] => chemistry ) [class_name] => Array ( [chemistry] => Chem101 [biology] => [biochemistry] => ) [professor_name] => Array ( [chemsitry] => Dr. Jones [biology] => [biochemistry] => ) [Submit] => )

Comment: Yes that is correct, all are being inserted instead of the ones where the checkbox is checked

Comment: Hey! finally got around  to changing and testing your piece of code! Works like a charm. It was all in the way I was writing the foreach statement! Thanks for you help! :)

Comment: I forgot to ask but what exactly does the first 3 lines of code in your answer mean so I can understand what I am doing for the future.

Comment: Hey there. They first 3 lines simply check both get and post variables for values if they are set. If neither of them are set, it gives them a default value. This method is much better than using `$_REQUEST` because request guesses at which one to use. you can see what request looks for [Here](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.request.php)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the isset function to check wether the checkbox is checked.

```
if (isset($_REQUEST['checkBoxName']));
   {

    $variable = $_REQUEST['checkBoxName'];
    }
```

Using this method you will only get the checkbox that has a value.

Hope this helps